# Jetpack Compose - Composable's height resizing with AnimatedVisibility

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to build a custom Drop down menu and I encountered some issues in animating its state. The animation is both **laggy** and **sketchy**, even on a real device and even on a release build (APK). The Compose version I'm using is `1.1.1`.

[image]

Observe the flicker (and the lag?).

The code:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    //header
    Column {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clickable { visible = !visible }
                .padding(8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Click me",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
            )
            Icon(
                modifier = Modifier.rotate(animateFloatAsState(if (visible) 180f else 0f).value),
                imageVector = Icons.Default.KeyboardArrowDown,
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }
        Divider(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            color = Color.Black.copy(ContentAlpha.disabled)
        )
    }
    //the 4 items
    Column {
        (1..4).forEach {
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = visible,
                enter = expandVertically(
                    spring(
                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow,
                        visibilityThreshold = IntSize.VisibilityThreshold
                    ),
                ),
                exit = shrinkVertically(),
            ) {
                Column {
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(16.dp),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Hello",
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
                        )
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.KeyboardArrowRight,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                    Divider(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        color = Color.Black
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I add some bottom padding to the bigger `Column` or if I make it occupy the whole screen's height, there's no more flicker, but I feel like that is a workaround and also I'm not sure whether the animation is lagging or not, so this wouldn't be a solution to all my problems. The parent `Column` wraps around its content and as the content size increases, it tries to "keep up" with the new size, but it doesn't do a perfect job. Am I using `AnimatedVisibility` improperly? How else could I create a custom Drop down menu?

Comment: I would advise to wrap whole expandable column and not all items separately. Probably lag would fix itself a swell.

Comment: @VygintasB Hmm.. I'm not really sure I understood you correctly. Either way, the "header" Column and the "items" Column should be separate Composables.

Comment: @Vygintas advices you to move `AnimatedVisibility` two levels upper: before `//the 4 items Column {`. This will animate the whole `Column` instead of animating each item separately, which it too heavy, as each next item depends on previous location which is changing on each frame

Comment: @PylypDukhov Maybe it would help, but I purposely wrapped each item around an `AnimatedVisibility` to obtain that specific animation.

Comment: In this case I suggest you [reporting](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) a bug, as your code seems fine for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Meanwhile you can animate it by hand - as your items have static height, you can get it with `Modifier.onSizeChanged`, place all items in a `Box` and animate offset depending on this value. It should be more performant as your calculations won't depend on other rows position.

Comment: @PylypDukhov Yeah, I should be able to make something more performant if I know beforehand that the items have the same height. Thanks. I'll try to work on It in the evening.